# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST in Laravel, did i have to update the route?

Tags: php, laravel

i got this error while trying to close (change the state) of actual object

```
 public function showclose(Request $request, $id) {
    $cashregister = CashRegister::find($id);
    if (!$request->ajax()) {
        return view('backend.cashregister.close', compact('cashregister', 'id'));
    } else {
        return view('backend.cashregister.modal.close', compact('cashregister', 'id'));
    }

}

public function close(Request $request, $id) {
    $cashregister                = CashRegister::find($id);
    $cashregister->status = 0;
    $cashregister->closedate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $cashregister->save();
    if (!$request->ajax()) {
        return redirect()->route('cashregister.index')->with('success', _lang('Closed Box'));
    } else {
        return response()->json(['result' => 'success', 'action' => 'update', 'message' => _lang('Closed Box'), 'data' => $cashregister, 'table' => '#cashregister_table']);
    }
}


Route::resource('cashregister','CashRegisterController');
        Route::get('cashregister/showclose/{id}', 'CashRegisterController@showclose')->name('cashregister.showclose');
        Route::post('cashregister/close/{id}', 'CashRegisterController@close')->name('cashregister.close');

<form method="post" class="ajax-screen-submit" autocomplete="off" action="{{ action('CashRegisterController@close', $id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field()}}
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">

<div class="row px-2">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr><td>{{ _lang('Box Quantity') }}</td><td>{{ $cashregister->startingamount }}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{ _lang('Open Date') }}</td><td>{{ $cashregister->created_at }}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{ _lang('Final Amount') }}</td><td>{{ $cashregister->finalamount }}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{ _lang('Close Date') }}</td><td>{{ $cashregister->closedate }}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{ _lang('Status') }}</td><td class='status'>{!! xss_clean(user_status($cashregister->status)) !!}</td></tr>
    </table>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger "><i class="ti-lock"></i>&nbsp;{{ _lang('Update') }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i cant update the value i want to do that showin the actual state adn then click to change the status but i got that error despite is post method

EDIT Changing the value to get works but why dont load the index view after update? any idea ?

Comment: Need to see your routes. On that file change it to post. As form alway accepts post for sending data to server

Comment: If you have changed the routes, clear cached one `php artisan route:clear`.